# Runtime error 449 Argument not optional

Tags: vba, excel

Have the below code

```
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(i).Names = Var_Name Then
            Exists = True
            Exists_Counter = Exists_Counter + 1
        End If
    Next I
```

It keeps giving me

> runtime error 449

whenever I run it. I have no idea how to fix it any idea?

Comment: it's name not names

Comment: @HarassedDad You may want to post that as the answer. Thats almost certainly the souce of the issue.

Comment: Also worth noting that Exists_Counter will never be `>1` since worksheets **must** have a unique name, and you aren't looping through workbooks (you're using an implicit call to `ActiveWorkbook`. Additionally, your `Next I` probably should be `Next i`. Finally, I strongly recommend not using underscores (`_`) in naming as these have special meaning to the interpreter. They are used for events, and interface implementation. Use `CamelCase` or `pascalCase` instead.

Comment: And the reason you are getting the `Argument not optional` error is because `Names` is a valid member of the `Worksheets` object. VBA is expecting arguments against the `Names` member though :)

Comment: And there are lot of sources with better code for this task, i.e. http://codevba.com/excel/sheet_exists.htm#.WlYjNbAiGUk or https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1743-excel-check-if-a-sheet-exists.html